# Save chrome performance profile without screenshots?

Tags: javascript, json, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. Recently, we had some performance issues with our web application and we captured a performance profile of the affected user with screenshots in Google chrome.

The user sent us the profile and its around ~300MB. I'm trying to figure out a way to remove the screenshots from that existing profile assuming that would trim down the size of the JSON file drastically.

Apologies for being subjective. But would really appreciate some help here, anyone?